# What are the frequencies of current in computers' external peripheral cables and internal buses?

Tags: cable, bus

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line), three different cases of current frequency are discussed along with the types of cables that are suitable for them:

> An **Extra Ordinary electrical cables** suffice to carry **low
>   frequency AC**, such as mains power, which reverses direction 100 to
>   120 times per second (cycling 50 to 60 times per second).
>
> However, they cannot be used to carry currents in the radio frequency
>   range or higher, which reverse direction millions to billions of times
>   per second, because the energy tends to radiate off the cable as radio
>   waves, causing power losses. Radio frequency currents also tend to
>   reflect from discontinuities in the cable such as connectors, and
>   travel back down the cable toward the source. These reflections act as
>   bottlenecks, preventing the power from reaching the destination. 
>   **Transmission lines** use specialized construction such as precise conductor dimensions and spacing, and impedance matching, to carry
>   electromagnetic signals with minimal reflections and power losses.
>   Types of transmission line include ladder line, coaxial cable,
>   dielectric slabs, stripline, optical fiber, and waveguides. The higher
>   the frequency, the shorter are the waves in a transmission medium.
>   Transmission lines must be used when **the frequency is high enough
>   that the wavelength of the waves begins to approach the length of the
>   cable used**.
>
> To conduct energy at **frequencies above the radio range**, such as
>   millimeter waves, infrared, and light, the waves become much smaller
>   than the dimensions of the structures used to guide them, so
>   transmission line techniques become inadequate and the methods of
>   **optics** are used.

I wonder what the frequencies are for the currents in computers' external peripheral cables, such as Ethernet cable, USB cable, and in computers' internal buses? Are the cables also made specially for the frequencies?

Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you that the PSU is an ACDC adaptor

Comment: @barlop: do you mean the currents in computers' external peripheral cables, such as Ethernet cable, USB cable, and in computers' internal buses are all DC, so their frequencies are all zero?

Comment: @Tim - Go Test It Out :-)

Comment: @Tim I suppose they'd all be DC. 0 freq. USB is 5V DC generated from the port,  USB has 4 wires,  2 for data and 2 for power, a + and GND.  Internal buses are DC(because of the PSU) but I don't know about the volts. Ethernet I don't know. Ethernet as far as I know doesn't have any power wires like + or GND, but according to this yahoo link    has about 2.5V  I would guess DC as ones i've seen haven't connected to any AC source. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080817012235AAkgJXB    And i'm sure the only thing in a computer taking AC In, is the PSU.

Comment: @barlop: in data wires of USB cables, and ethernet, all that are transmitted are electrical currents, right?

Comment: Ethernet tends to use Cat5 or Cat6 cables, which has 8 wires . 4 twisted pairs. one pair is used for sending. Another pair is for receiving. And the other two pairs are for when Gigabit ethernet is in use.  I suppose you're right about electric current in usb and ethernet, I don't know the electronics, I guess there's a voltage, but there are no + and GND in Ethernet. There are + and GND in USB.

Comment: @barlop: What does "+" mean? Is it different from GND?

Comment: I'm not an electronic geek.. and I don't really understand what Voltage is, what is meant by differences in electric potential. But yes + is different from GND. Generally the + wire is colored e.g. Red, and always the GND wire is Black.

Comment: Contrary to what has been claimed here, the data in USB, serial, Ethernet, and everything else mentioned here is transmitted as AC. If  you want to be technical we would say it's AC with a DC offset. The fact that there's only a DC power supply and that the signals never swing below 0 volts is irrelevant. (Well, serial does, and so does Ethernet... never mind.) That doesn't make them DC. If they were DC they could not convey any data!

Answer (score 1):

> **I wonder what the frequencies are for the currents in computers' external peripheral cables, such as Ethernet cable, USB cable, and in computers' internal buses?**

This information should be available in either the appropriate Wikipedia articles or in the relevant technical standards (which are probably referred to in those articles)

In general the signalling rate or frequency is not the same as the data rate (due to encoding, the use of multiple transmission channels (e.g. pairs) and other factors) but dividing by ten will give you a (very) rough idea.

For example, 1000Base-T Ethernet has a data rate of 10^9 bits/second, so you could assume a signalling frequency that is 100 MHz.

For the actual rate, use Google (which would lead you to [relevant articles](http://octoscope.com/English/Collaterals/Articles/octoScope_GbitEthernet_GEC98_19980606.pdf))

> **Are the cables also made specially for the frequencies?**

Yes.

Sometimes the data transmission standards are made to match an existing cable specification. For example, I believe the original 10Base-T spec was designed so people could use existing premises wiring standards that had been designed for voice telephony not for Ethernet. This reduced the cost of deploying 10Base-T and may (in a small way) have helped sales of Ethernet products.

---

Update:

If you want a rigorous answer, be careful about using vague terms like [electricity](http://amasci.com/miscon/whatis.html).

Note that (so far as I know) most electrical signalling systems used with computer peripherals nowadays look at voltage changes at specific frequencies, they don't look at current (c.f. current-loop interface). So it isn't useful to think of "current frequency".

Note: I am not an electronic engineer.

Comment: No that's bits per second. Totally the wrong layer. He's asking about the electricity. Not the bits. Electricity is lower level than bits.

Comment: What is the difference between "signal frequency" and electricity frequency?

Comment: @Tim all I can say there  is frequency is a thing per second. Measured in Hz which is a unit for things per second.

Comment: @barlop: isn't that what I said in my second paragraph (it's what I meant)

Comment: @Tim: When people say "electricity frequency" I tend to guess they mean the frequency of domestic electrical power supply in a particular locale - for example 120 Volts alternating current (AC) at 60 Hz. If so, that is completely unrelated.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: signals for data that is transmitted in theose cables are electricity currents, aren't they? So the frequency of signal and the frequency of the electricity current are the same concept?

Comment: @Tim: Sort of. My answer is simplified. Some signalling systems use multiple carrier frequencies. But yes by signalling I mean electrical signalling, so the two are pretty much the same. If you want a rigorous and precise answer, it may be better to ask in electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Isn't the electricity already DC because the power adapter is AC->DC converter?

Comment: @Tim: No, not for that reason if you are talking about (say) the "electricity" in an Ethernet 8P8C (RJ45) socket in your computer. A DC powered device can synthesize an AC signal.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Do you mean that although the computer is using DC directly from the power adapter on its power chord, some parts of the computer convert DC back to AC again, and the currents in Ethernet cables (and possibly in USB cables and internal buses) are not DC but AC?

Comment: @Tim: On reflection, maybe I should have directed you to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on *actual problems* that you face." This site is not suited to discussions or tutorials on the fundamentals of electricity, data comms or information theory. It's uncharitable of me I know, but I'm worrying that you are in danger of becoming a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). I'm happy to help but it would be best if you could consider separately asking narrow answerable single practical questions.

Comment: @Tim electricity is kind of like a holy grail, not many people in computers grasp it, and even electricians might just know it on more of a practical level.it's very very hard to find answers, for example, what is voltage. i've yet to figure it out to near my satisfaction. There is a field called electro-chemistry and maybe electrochemists have good answers. Do comment if you find any answers! Sometimes a link to a chat window comes up when there are many comments in which case use that and write there. I do suggest as redgrittybrick did,  electronics.stackexchange as something to try as well.

Comment: @barlop: I got some nice answers here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38989/computer-bus-frequency-and-electricity-frequency